# Adding margins between multiple columns using bootstrap 3.1.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to have 4 cols inside a row with equal margins but i did not get the desired look

here is my html code

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading">Account Summary</div>

        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="row center-block text-center summary_boxes">

                <div class="col-sm-3">2500</div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">1300</div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">1000</div>

                <div class="col-sm-3">1000</div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

css code

```
.summary_boxes div
{
   background-color:#eee;
   border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
   border-radius:3px;
}
```

and this is the result

[image: this is the result]

Comment: What is the expected result? Also, please provide all code and fiddle if possible

Comment: By adding margin to boostrap div you will push your contents off into a new Row instead try reading the .col-md-offset-* classes (offset by 1 col)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that Bootstrap uses padding for columns and columns themselves shouldn't have additional styles applied directly to them.

What you should do is make child elements of the columns and give those the style you want, then you will have the "margin" you are looking for.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Account Summary</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row center-block text-center summary_boxes">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><span>2500</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><span>1300</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><span>1000</span></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"><span>1000</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the style:

```
.col-sm-3 > span {
    background: red;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle, you might have to make the output window wider to correctly see the result depending on your screen resolution http://jsfiddle.net/LysqB/